# How can I loop through (and display) a series of elements based on a select value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question on a form, which asks how much of a certain product is required:

```
<select name="select-number" id="select-number">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Based on the answer to this question, I want to show a subsequent section for each option (in this example, 0 to 3 sections would be shown):

```
<div class="item-details" id="item-1">
    Follow-up questions item 1
</div>

<div class="item-details" id="item-2">
    Follow-up questions item 2
</div>

<div class="item-details" id="item-3">
    Follow-up questions item 3
</div>
```

I have the CSS set up so that I just need to loop through the correct number of `div`s with the class `.item-details` and add the class `.state--visible`.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this? I guess I need to have a `for` loop based on the value of my select, but so far I have failed. My code can be seen [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/gLWBe/). Cheers.

**EDIT**

I don't think I explained myself very well. Rather than just showing *one* section based on the option selected, I need to loop through and show all the previous sections as well. So, if I select option 2 from the dropdown, both `#item-1` and `#item-2` should be shown (the first two instances of the `.item-details` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZpJm6/1/)

```
$('#select-number').change(function() {
    var details = $('.item-details'),
        number = $(this).val();

    details.removeClass('state--visible');

    for(var i=1; i<=number; i++){
        $('#item-' + i).addClass('state--visible');   
    }

}).change();
```

Another way of doing it would be: (replace the above `for` loop):

```
$.each(this.options, function(i, val){
    $('#item-' + val.value).addClass('state--visible');   
    if(val.value == number){
        return false;
    }
});
```

The benefit of this is it's slightly more flexible. It doesn't rely on the option values being numerical and consecutive. So you could have for example `<option value="aaa">` paired with `#item-aaa`.

Comment: Assuming the `item-x` IDs are unique like they should be, you could probably safely get rid of the check on the length and just use `$('#item-' + number).show();`. jQuery will only show the first item it finds anyway.

Comment: Yes the check can safely be removed, it's only useful if you don't want to call `.show()` when the target element doesn't exist for example `#item-9`. It won't error without the check though so it makes no difference really.

Comment: Please check out my edit, explaining a bit better what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez updated answer and demo to do that.

Comment: @MrCode - I achieved the same thing using `slice`: `details.removeClass('state--visible').slice(0, number).addClass('state--visible');`. Do you know which will be more efficient, this or the `for` loop? It's kinda moot as both work very quickly, I am just curious.

Comment: I would say the `for` loop would be slightly faster because anything native to the browser is always faster than something that's user defined (ie `.slice()`. If you want to compare, have a look at http://jsperf.com/

Comment: Interestingly, the `slice` approach seems to be [significantly faster](http://jsperf.com/for-v-slice)

Comment: That is interesting, I suspect the for loop is held up by the repeated calls to create the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$("#select-number").change(function() {
    $(".item-details").hide(); //hide all others
    $("#item-" + this.value).show();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gLWBe/2/